# In-memory file system creating using node js with give constraints

Tags: node.js

Implement an in-memory file system with the following interface:

mkdir(path: string): void

writeFile(path: string, data: string): void

readFile(path: string): string

Assumptions & Clarifications

Assumptions about the file system:

Root directory exists ie. /

Assumptions about the path:

Path will always be a full path from root ie. /foo/bar

Memory limit

Assume its unlimited

Writing a file to a path that already exists

Overwrite the original file

Write file/mkdir to a path where the parent directory doesn’t exist

Error, the full parent path must exist

Read file from a directory

Error

I need to create in-memory file system using node js with give conditions please help using that

Comment: Can you please explain what specific issue you're facing, and what steps you have taken to resolve the issue so far, and post the snippet of code where you believe the issue lies?